# Unable to run VS project on Docker

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, docker

First, I was learning how to work with Docker from the command line.

Then, wanted to see what I could do with Visual Studio.

**My goal is** to use Visual Studio 2017 to create an ASP.NET Core web API and develop, debug, test and deploy that web API using containers.

The solution has two projects: one is the usual ASP.NET Core project and the other is one called Docker Compose:

[image]

As you can see, it's the same Program.cs and Startup.cs that you can see in any other ASP.NET Core application, the same type of controller, so there's nothing in the C# code that knows anything about Docker or containers or the operating environment that it's going to be in.

The only thing Docker related about this particular project, is the presence of a Docker file (you can see it opened in the image with the instructions to build another image).

The particular image is going to be a Linux image. So, one thing I needed to do was going to Docker menu and switch to Linux containers:

[image]

**Steps to reproduce the issue**

1. Launch VS2017
2. Create a new project, C#, ASP.NET Core Web Application (enabling Docker support)
3. Run and debug using Docker (F5)

**Expected behavior**

Application runs and allows its debugging.

**Actual behavior**

Build fails due to error:

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: docker-compose, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 config
1>services:
1>  pswebapi:
1>    build:
1>      args:
1>        source: obj/Docker/empty/
1>      context: C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\PsWebApi
1>      dockerfile: Dockerfile
1>    entrypoint: tail -f /dev/null
1>    environment:
1>      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
1>      DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER: '1'
1>    image: pswebapi:dev
1>    labels:
1>      com.microsoft.visualstudio.targetoperatingsystem: linux
1>    ports:
1>    - 80/tcp
1>    volumes:
1>    - C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\PsWebApi:/app:rw
1>    - C:\Users\tiagoperes\clrdbg:/clrdbg:ro
1>    - C:\Users\tiagoperes\.nuget\packages:/root/.nuget/packages:ro
1>version: '2.0'
1>docker  ps --filter "status=running" --filter "name=dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_" --format {{.ID}} -n 1
1>PsWebApi -> C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\PsWebApi\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\PsWebApi.dll
1>C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File "C:\Users\tiagoperes\AppData\Local\Temp\GetVsDbg.ps1" -Version vs2017u1 -RuntimeID debian.8-x64 -InstallPath "C:\Users\tiagoperes\clrdbg\vsdbg"
1>Info: Using vsdbg version '15.1.10630.1'
1>Info: Using Runtime ID 'linux-x64'
1>Info: Latest version of VsDbg is present. Skipping downloads
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.release.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 kill
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.release.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 down --rmi local --remove-orphans
1>Removing dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ...
1>[1A[2K
1>Removing dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... [32mdone[0m
1>[1BRemoving network dockercompose1712142422_default
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 kill
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 down --rmi local --remove-orphans
1>Removing network dockercompose1712142422_default
1>Network dockercompose1712142422_default not found.
1>docker-compose -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.override.yml" -f "C:\Users\tiagoperes\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\PsWebApi\docker-compose.vs.debug.yml" -p dockercompose1712142422 up -d --build
1>Creating network "dockercompose1712142422_default" with the default driver
1>Building pswebapi
1>Step 1/6 : FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:1.1
1> ---> c87149836213
1>Step 2/6 : ARG source
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> f48760163a33
1>Step 3/6 : WORKDIR /app
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> cb7ee352c5c5
1>Step 4/6 : EXPOSE 80
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> fc3d1d4fcfb5
1>Step 5/6 : COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> b6ef96f437c0
1>Step 6/6 : ENTRYPOINT dotnet PsWebApi.dll
1> ---> Using cache
1> ---> 0fdc28e1982b
1>Successfully built 0fdc28e1982b
1>Successfully tagged pswebapi:dev
1>Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ...
1>Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1
1>[1A[2K
1>Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... [31merror[0m
1>[1B
1>ERROR: for dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>ERROR: for pswebapi  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: The "PrepareForLaunch" task failed unexpectedly.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: Creating network "dockercompose1712142422_default" with the default driver
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Building pswebapi
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: [1A[2K
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... [31merror[0m
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: [1B
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: ERROR: for dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: ERROR: for pswebapi  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Encountered errors while bringing up the project..
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: For more troubleshooting information, go to http://aka.ms/DockerToolsTroubleshooting ---> Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.CommandLineClientException: Creating network "dockercompose1712142422_default" with the default driver
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Building pswebapi
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... 
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: [1A[2K
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Creating dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1 ... [31merror[0m
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: [1B
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: ERROR: for dockercompose1712142422_pswebapi_1  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: ERROR: for pswebapi  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerComposeClient.<ExecuteAsync>d__18.MoveNext()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.DockerWorkspace.<PrepareForLaunchAsync>d__14.MoveNext()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018: --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.DotNet.Docker.BuildTasks.DockerBaseTask.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\Docker\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(192,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
1>Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Additional information**

OS: Windows 10

Comment: Open Hyper-V Manager and see if you have a Linux VM there.

Comment: yes there is one called MobyLinuxVM which is running with the memory Ive given in the DfW advance section but with no CPU usage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've gone through similar issues.

This is how you can solve it.

1. Windows Power-Shell and run the following command:

   docker ps -a

Can you see something?

2. If yes, and you can, go to your Docker for Windows settings,

> Reset > Reset to factory defaults

Then, make your login.

3. Go to Windows Power-Shell run the following command:

   netstat -an | findstr :445

you should see something like this:

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    10.0.75.1:445          10.0.75.1:50609        ESTABLISHE
TCP    10.0.75.1:50609        10.0.75.1:445          ESTABLISHE
TCP    [::]:445               [::]:0                 LISTENING
```

3. Go to your Firewall and check if for both private and public you are allowing the connection:

[windows firewall - how yours should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCZre.png)

4. Check your Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and see if you have any rule blocking the connection to the port 445, tcp and udp. If yes, and they are enabled, disable by right clicking and selecting disable.
5. Go to your File Explorer and test if you can access:

> \\10.0.75.1\c

6. Go to your Docker for Windows settings, shared drive, share your C.

Some of my friends reported the following problem:

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#firewall-rules-for-shared-drives

but if you followed all the steps until now, you shouldn't have any problem with it.

7. Now you should be good to go, go to your VS and run and debug using Docker (F5).

**Hope this can help you.**

Comment: yes, I had that problem sharing the C drive. I disabled windows firewall to be able to share it, then enabled it again. Of course this wouldn't fix the problem.

Then, went to Windows Firewall with Advanced Security and had those 2 ports blocked. It might be from a time I've used driver booster to get protection because of WannaCry and I didn't even realize.

Thank you for the help, this got me going

Comment: yea, most likely would be the firewall

Answer (score 0):

```
1>ERROR: for pswebapi  Cannot start service pswebapi: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:339: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:57: mounting \\\"/C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi\\\" to rootfs \\\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/318ea1b0b7d0bbc13e75c543448338e655d825f58c41a88c5ca7d03680a16fac/merged\\\" at \\\"/app\\\" caused \\\"stat /C/Users/tiagoperes/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Projects/PsWebApi/PsWebApi: host is down\\\"\""
```

This is an issue with the shared drives in your docker daemon. Make sure that in your docker settings, under shared drives, you have the C drive ticked and then restart the docker daemon.

These shared drives links forward your local filesystem through to the machine hosting the docker daemon and without them working correctly docker is unable to do any volume mounting from the host system.

Comment: Yea but drive C was ticked and restarted before. apart from that, in Docker for Windows (DfW) settings, the only other thing changed was to start Docker when I log in. Hyper V was also enabled, bt that was before installing DfW